# Multiple Toggle. / Hide Show / Close others while open

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, toggle

Still a noob when it comes to this part of programming. I have a question regarading something I "solved" with the toggle function. I have 3 buttons ( placed in different divs on the page, so it's not a tab toggle ). What I try to achieve is when I have a button active and I click on another one, I want the active one to be closed. I looked up some jfiddle posts here with something similar, tried to implement it to the page and figure it out myself but nothing worked for me so far. The function I currently use for one button is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#toggle5').click(function() {
        $('.infotext').fadeToggle('fast');
        return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

It works just fine for one button to close and open it, but I have no idea where to start when I want two more buttons and let them interact with each other as mentioned before. Anybody has an idea how to do that ? And is the toggle function even the right function here ? I'd like to thank in advance for what ever answer I get here, great community.

Comment: Can you give an example or make your own fiddle, because I still don't understand what you want.

Comment: example -> I open "box1" by click "toggle1" , so box1 is visible. Now I open "box2" while "box1" is opened by click "toggle2" so "box2" is visible and "box1" is hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/pHCN3/2/).

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
    var tClass = $(this).attr("id"),
        content = $("div.content." + tClass),
        link = $(this);

    $("div.content:not('." + tClass + "')").fadeOut("fast");
    $("a").not(link).text("Open");
    content.fadeToggle("fast", function() {
        link.hide().text((content.is(":visible") ? "Close" : "Open")).fadeIn("fast");
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

If by closed you mean disabled then the code block bellow will do the trick.
Also, this will work only if your buttons are submit or button type.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
        // click event for the #toggle5 button
        $('#toggle5').click(function() {
           // check if the #toggle6 is disabled
           if ( !$('#toggle6').is(':disabled')) { 
              // if is not disabled, then disabled it
              $('#toggle6').attr("disabled", "disabled");
           }
           return false;
        });
  });
</script>
```

If your buttons are links you will need to fire the preventDefault event

Docs here: http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.preventDefault.28.29

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
        // click event for the #toggle5 button
        $('#toggle5').click(function() {
           $('#toggle6').on("click",function(e){
              // check if we hire the preventDefault event already
              if(!e.isDefaultPrevented()
                 e.preventDefault();
           });
           return false;
        });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the anwsers. With the help of your guys I solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

This will allow multiple toggle elements. Click toggle first one to open. Click to open the second one and it will close the first one and then open the 2nd one. So forth and so on. Can also close toggles with a click without having to open another one.

The HTML Markup

```
<div class="toggle">See Stuff</div>
<div class="paragraph">
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Video</p>
  <p>Image</p>
</div>
```

The jQuery

```
<script>
 $('.paragraph').hide();
 $('.toggle').click(function() {
   var panel = $(this).next()
   $('.paragraph').not(panel).slideUp();
   panel.slideToggle({
    direction: "down"
 }, 1000);
 });
</script>
```